# How to split a table cell vertically

Tags: html, css, cell

I know a similar question on this topic has been asked, but doesn't look like there was a definitive solution.  So with that, here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/24/

I want to split the table cell under the "Pick" heading vertically.  I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require JS or anything wonky, if possible.

Comment: You can create a new table inside that cell and split it.

Comment: Dude you need to switch the accepted answer below to the one by Felipe

Comment: After some examination I have to agree with Phphelp that the easiest and most semantically non-insane answer to your question is:  nested tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really split a cell vertically, but if you add another cell after it in each of the table body rows and give the heading row a `colspan="2"` you can have two different cells under one heading.

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/26/

Answer (score 18):

Actually you could have used `rowspan=2` HTML property for the other cells, and then you could have you cell splited vertically

http://jsfiddle.net/Ty44J/

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: me neither lol, it generally happens when the OP just vanishes, but it seems that @keruilin is still active...